# Shield bash with magic shield - is it a magic weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Say I've got this Dwarf, Dwarfnir. He has a +1 magic shield that he's pretty happy about. He gets into a big fight and decides that, while it's all fine and dandy to hit things with his warhammer, that he'd sure like to smack some faces sideways with his +1 magic shield, especially that weird thing with all the eyes that seems to be unharmed by his wimpy and totally-not-magic hammer.

Would such an attack benefit from the shield being a magic +1 shield the same way as if it were a magic +1 club (with +1 to attack and damage rolls, and bypassing nonmagic weapon resistances)?

I get an understanding from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59536/how-does-shield-bashing-work) how the shield bash would work and that proficiency wouldn't apply, but I'm wondering specifically about Dwarfnir getting that sweet sweet magic weapon bonus.